# Library Search Permissions

Tags: search

We have sites that have multiple repositories, with those repositories each having custom permissions. Certain people are able to use search on these sites, the ones with the Owner and Member permissions, but other groups (the ones with custom permissions) yield no results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is actually what makes SharePoint Search Great is that when a user is querying SharePoint, SharePoint search apply security trimming based on the user identity and permission level. This is why you will see certain user with custom permission or user with explicit permission get different result set. So the best way to do it is to start classifying your content and categorize them so you apply the permission easily. Sometimes, it is better to move content from one container to another (document library to another one or document library to another site or to its own site collection and maybe also create different result sources to get better search experience!)

Comment: I understand that. The group in question had access to three entire libraries however, and none of those documents appear in search.

Comment: So, this could mean that it is Search problem and the content of these document libraries have not been crawled. Did you check if a (site collection admin) searches, do the documents show up? Did you try to reindex the document library (DL Settings --> Advanced--> Reindex DL)..Check SP Search Service on CA if there are any issue encountered with the content of these documents?

Comment: The documents show up for me, an admin; the owners group and the members group. They do not show up for groups with custom permissions. I don't think it's a crawl problem.

Comment: ok, is the custom permission on the document library level, folder level, or item level? do a small test, choose one of the files that are not coming up in search, and see its permission level (I am not sure if it is SP 2013 or prior, because the way to check on the permission level is little different) and if the user in question got access to this document or not.

Comment: Set at library level.

Comment: And the team in question does have access at both the document level and the library level. And we don't use folders.